# numpy vstack with images

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am writing a function to read pixel data from images and store them in a numpy array to further do a train/test split.

When I run this code it throws an exception saying that all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly.

I am not sure why this issue happens and how to fix it.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import os

X = np.array([])
y = []

categories = {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 2
}

root = data_dir + '/cropped_resized(128,128)/'

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        img_path = os.path.join(path,name)
        category = categories[os.path.basename(path)]
        im = Image.open(img_path)
        img_pixels = list(im.getdata())
        width, height = im.size
        X = np.vstack((X, img_pixels))
        #X = np.concatenate((X, img_pixels), axis=0)
        y.append(category)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y)
```

Here is an example of a picture that fails

[image]

Comment: Using `vstack` in the loop is slow.  Better to accumulate a list like you do with `y `

Comment: Thanks, indeed this is much quicker that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide if you want your images as RGB or Greyscale and ensure that they are so on load.

Specifically, change this line:

```
im = Image.open(img_path)
```

to

```
im = Image.open(img_path).convert('RGB')
```

or

```
im = Image.open(img_path).convert('L')
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - the pictures are RGB - by enforcing this conversion I still have the same error message `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`

Comment: I feared that some of your images may be palettised and therefore single channel rather than 3-channel. The next best idea is to print `im.size` and `im.mode` for each image.

Comment: This check has been made already `(128, 128) / RGB` for all of them.

Comment: Can you share the first image in the list and the first image that fails please?

Comment: I've uploaded a sample picture, any picture of the dataset fails.

Comment: Aha! Your initial array has `dtype=np.float64`, subsequent ones will be `dtype=np.uint8`

Comment: Also, you should simply assign the first image to `X` and concatenate later ones.

Comment: Thanks, you found my problem - it was indeed the initial assignment that incorrect.